c# Stream a small S3 file from an Lambda to a http response
I have a very small file in S3 that I want to return from an AWS Lambda.  I'm able to get the file from S3 with no problem and if I save the file to a drive (while running in Visual Studio) the file and format are correct.  However, when I try to return the result from the Lambda I get a file nearly double the size of the file (400+KB vs. 237KB).
        var bucketRequest = new GetObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = uri.Bucket,
            Key = uri.Key,
        };
        using var bucketResponse = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(bucketRequest);
        //await bucketResponse.WriteResponseStreamToFileAsync(@"C:\temp\ohmy.bz2", false, CancellationToken.None);

        await using var responseStream = bucketResponse.ResponseStream;
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new BinaryWriter(ms);

        var buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = await responseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, CancellationToken.None)
                   .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)) > 0)
        {
            writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        writer.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;

        return new APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse
        {
            StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Body = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray()),
            IsBase64Encoded = false,
            Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"Content-Type", "application/x-bzip2"},
                { "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=sites.bz2" }
            }
        };

If I write to a file as shown in this line
await bucketResponse.WriteResponseStreamToFileAsync(@"C:\temp\ohmy.bz2", false, CancellationToken.None);

The resulting file is correct.
My guess is that trying to convert this binary file to some kind of string is where the problem is, e.g.
Body = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray()),

My thinking is if I could return a stream directly instead of trying to convert it to a string I may be able to get what I want.
This question (How to return a stream from AWS ApiGateway?) is similar to what I want but my file is really small so no need to use the S3 pre-signed URL.
Edit
If I change the signature of the function to
public async Task<Stream> FunctionHandler(APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)

I get the correct results when I return the memoryStream directly.  However, I need to also set some headers which I can't do when the return type is Stream.

See answer in ticket https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/discussions/1527 you should use HttpApi, then you can stream binary content. But seeing other tickets, it might be not enough and you would need to custom brew your lambda server responses https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/1574

@eocron It appears the link you have is for when using "serverless" apis, specifically with builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.HttpApi) I'm using a straight up lambda

Hmm, strange, the title specifically about Lambdas.

it is about lambda, but using minimal api.  mine is using straight up lambda where signature is like public async Task<APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse> FunctionHandler(APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)

Oh, I get it, try to Base64 encode your binary data and put it into body. Also, set IsBase64Encoded = true. According to docs, you can do this for all binary content-types.
